# Как сделать docker image с двумя контейнерами?

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, apache-kafka

Я совсем новичек в докере и мне дали задание залить свое приложение в докер, но вот беда , мое приложение использует кафку и задача такова, что мне нужно помимо jar файла залить еще и кафку в докер, так чтобы все работало в отрыве. Сейчас я сделал это приложение и локально запускаю и кафку и код и все работает. Задача как раз в том чтобы переместить все в докер, так что прошу помощи, может статьи какие или еще что, потому что в инете не особо нашел полезного для моей ситуации. Заранее спасибо !

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: ваше java приложение можно упаковать в отдельный образ, а для kafka использовать готовый образ, например от bitnami, и потом это все можно объединить с помощью docker-compose